# can not connect database server in mysql?

Tags: mysql

[image]

I changed max_connection value is 1 / hour in mysql server.than I close the mySql workbench and I again try to open.It shows the above error what can I do can any one tell how to fix this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check the points mentioned in the error? They kind of sum up all the possible issues ;)

Comment: @AsG how can i log in the same connection if i tried to open new connection it is all so says access denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem is solved using following way

Actually what i did wrong is i set max_connection_per_hour=1 in my workbench settings.

that's why i can't open the connection for some period of time .now i solved using terminal with the use of following command

$ mysql -u root -p

then i just enter the password for root user than i use the following command

mysql>$ grant usage on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' with max_connections_per_hour 0;

after than i can open my connection with out any problem.

i tried this command many times but after one hour only it works for me before that it gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it a reasonable value. To do this login with the `sa` account. Without any other connections you should be able to do this Then set the parameter to a reasonable value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the mysql server, from command line as root do `mysqld restart`. Restarting workbench does not kill the connections.

Comment: how to change the max-connection value with out open a connection

Comment: Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-monitor/2.3/en/mem-config-properties-file-location.html
You need to restart the server after editing to apply.